# How do I replace Windows 8.1 frequently visited folders to recently?

Tags: windows-8.1, jumplist

Unlike the previous OS I've had (Win7), instead of showing me recently visited folders, Windows 8.1 only provides me with a list of my most frequently visited folders.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8P0nN.png]

It is comfortable, I'll admit. But why do I need this when I have the ability to pin folders?

I would rather have my recently visited folders instead if possible.